# Web Scraping - unable to print phone numbers using python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Attempting to scrape data from [real-estate agent page](https://www.raywhite.com/contact/?type=People&target=people&suburb=Sydney%2C%20NSW%202000&radius=10&firstname=&lastname=&_so=people) for project

I was able to get both Name and Job Description for all, however only a small number of phone numbers.

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.raywhite.com/contact/?type=People&target=people&suburb=Sydney%2C+NSW+2000&radius=5&firstname=&lastname=&_so=people'

# opening connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"card horizontal-split vcard"})

for container in containers:
    agent_name = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-name"})
    name = agent_name[0].text

    agent_role = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-role"})
    role = agent_role[0].text

    phone = container.find("a").text

    print("name: " + name)
    print("role: " + role)
    print("phone: " + phone)
```

This is a sample of the first couple that were printed, with only the first two agents have their phone numbers listed:

```
name: Mark Constantine
role: Principal
phone: 0418 222 643
name: Dawn Veloskey
role: Operations Manager
phone: 0418 449 600
name: Yvonne Lau
role: Sales
phone:

name: Anthony Cavallaro
role: Managing Director | Selling Principal
phone:

name: Ciara OConnor
role: Sales Executive
phone:

name: Michael Buium
role: Commercial Sales Manager and Auctioneer
phone:

name: Albert Hui
role: Senior Commercial Property Manager
phone:

name: Jessie Yee
role: Associate Director, Commercial Leasing & Management
phone:
```

Not sure why other phone numbers are not being printed, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because the first two don't have photographs, otherwise the photo is the first "a" tag.

replace:

```
phone = container.find("a").text
```

with:

```
 filterfn = lambda x: 'href' in x.attrs and x['href'].startswith("tel")
 phones = map(lambda x: x.text,filter(filterfn,container.findAll("a"))) 

 for phone in phones:
     print("phone number: " + phone)
```

Comment: Thanks @XingzhouLiu, however when I try to run it, this error comes up: name: Mark Constantine
role: Principal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toby\Desktop\Webscrape\scrape - mark4.py", line 28, in <module>
    print("phone: " + phone)
TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: I kept phones a list b/c some have more than one phone number. You can also use print("phones:" + repr(phones)) or see edits above.